# JAVA jtable passing value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am facing the problem of passing value to print it out in the jtable. I am trying to pass my data variable to the table but I am getting error once I trying to run the project. The image below shown what i tried.[image]

I declare these 2 variable in global.

```
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

String[] headers = {"IP", "Port", "Destination", "Port"};
```

I pass in the value what i read from the text file into data variable as this:

```
Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
row.add(allTCP.get(x).getTCPSourceIP());
row.add(allTCP.get(x).getTCPSourcePort());
row.add(allTCP.get(x).getTCPDestIP());
row.add(allTCP.get(x).getTCPDestPort());
data.add(row);
```

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong or what shall i do in order for me pass in the value to output as table form. By the way, I designed my table in third tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the `DefaultTableModel` API.

You can create a `DefaultTableModel` using:

1. an Array of column names and a 2 dimensional array of data, or
2. an Vector of column names and a Vector of Vectors for the data.

You can't create the model using an array and a Vector.

Comment: sorry, do u mind to gv me some example code? because I do not know which variable shall i assign to, my case above i was confused also because if i am using a textarea i will code it as jtextarea1.settext("abc") but for jtable i hv no any idea on which variable shall i pass to.

Comment: @Aaron,  Learning how to read the API is a basic programming skill you need to develop. I have no idea what that image represents. It looks like you are using an IDE and I have no idea how to write code with your IDE. If you want some example code then read the JTable API. You will find a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables`. The tutorial explains the basics and has several working programs you can download an play with.